# Is it possible to custom rewrite install.packages() in R so as to not need to specify quotes around the the package name?

Tags: r

For example, in

`install.packages("caret")`

one must include the quotes around `caret`. I am wondering if theres a way to avoid that. I have written:

```
inst.packages <- function (x) {
    install.packages(as.character(paste(x)))
}
```

but the issue here is that `caret` doesn't exist as an object. Therefore,

```
inst.packages(caret)
```

gives `Error in paste(caret) : object 'caret' not found.`

Is there a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: try `inst.packages <- function(x) install.packages(deparse(substitute(x)))`

Comment: Have a look here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works

```
inst.pkg <- function(...){

   install.packages(sapply(substitute({ ... })[-1], deparse))

}


inst.pkg(caret)
```